# PHP library that implements MPI - Verified by Visa and SecureCode?

Tags: php, credit-card

What are the solutions? Anything open source. If only commercial applications, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly unlikely you'll find anything open source imho, but willing to hear otherwise. My reasoning for that is the costs involved for having an MPI accredited with Visa/MasterCard are.. significant (if I remember correctly it was around $5000 per scheme?). And any open source solution would need to go through accreditation for each 'build'.

So you'll most likely need to look at prebuilt commercial offerings.  It was a good few years ago now, but we went with nsoftware, one of the first to market a standalone MPI

http://www.nsoftware.com/products/3dsecure
http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/epayment/technologies.aspx?sku=BPP5-A